# Replace all occurrences of a value in a column

Tags: matlab, octave

I need to replace several occurences of a number (5) in the first column of my matrix for -1. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mind posting what you've done so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
A(A(:,1)==5,1) = -1
```

Hope this helps.